# Python v3 inconsistent regex match returns

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a small python script which takes a log file, matches strings within it and saves them and another custom string "goal " to another text file. Then I take some values from the second file and add them to a list. The problem is that depending on the length of the custom string (e.g. "goalgoalgoal   ") the lists with the values varies in length - currently, I'm working with a log file which includes 1031 matches of the string "goal ", but the length of list varies from everything between ~980 and 1029.

Here is the code:

```
for line in inputfile:
    if "Started---" in line:
       startTime = line[11:23]
       testfile.write("\n"+"Start"+"\n"+"goal "+ startTime+"\n")
       counterLines +=1
    elif "done!" in line: 
       testfile.write("\n"+find_between(line, "| ", "done!")+"\n")
    elif "Errors:" in line:
       testfile.write("\n"+"Errors:"+line.split("Errors:",1)[1]+"\n")
    elif "Warnings:" in line:
       testfile.write("\n"+"Warnings:"+line.split("Warnings:",1)[1]+"\n")
    elif "Successes:" in line:
       testfile.write("\n"+"Successes:"+line.split("Successes:",1)[1]+"\n")
    elif "END---" in line:
       endTime = line[11:23]
       testfile.write("\n"+"End"+"\n"+"endTime "+ endTime+"\n")
    else:
       print("nothing found")

testfileread = open(filePath+"\\testFile.txt", "r")

startTimesList = []
endTimesList =   []

for line in testfileread:
    matchObj = re.match(r'goal', line)
    if matchObj:
       startTimesList.append(line)

print(len(startTimesList))
```

Do you have ideas why the code doesn't work as expected?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's due to the fact that you don't flush `testFile.txt` after writing is completed - as a result, there is unpredictable amount of data in the file when you start reading it. Calling `testfile.flush()` should fix the problem. Alternatively, wrap the writing logic in a `with` block.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I might be missing something like this, but wasn't sure what.